# Comparing two files, writing update/delete/insert output files

Tags: perl, csv

I'm working on a script that will check changes made based on 2 files. The files share a common id and if a match is made it has to compare 5 elements (with basic info, adres, zipcode etc). If one or more elements don't match it should push the changes from the second file at the end of the first file (so afterwards I can easily view the changes made)

The first file is the basis and the other file is from a month later and contains changes in three ways: I covered the first already. If an ID doesn't match it should write it to a new file. This can happen in 2 ways: The id in the new file doesn't exist anymore (so it's probably been removed), this will be the second outputfile and the third file is where the id in the old file doesn't exist (which means it's new).

I've been concentrating my efforts on the first part, the comparison of elements. It wasn't hard comparing the elements but I can't seem to figure out how to add the elements from the second file to the end of the existing array properly. When I use push the variable it doesn't add at the end but shows up on the next line, so I think there's a new line in between there but I removed it with chomp. So why is this happening?

The second question: How can I easily accomplish the second part, checking for new/old ID's and writing to their own file.

This is how far I got now (which is not far). This is only the comparison part, still working how to incorporate writing the 2 other files which contain the old (removed) / new entries. How I'm trying to get it:

Bad:

```
 1204;Hotel New York;Street 4;AABBCC;New York;12345679;www.hotelnewyork.com;52.3662946;3.876277;5365;3
 783;Hotel Amsterdam;Damstraat 10;1234 AB;Amsterdam;234567890;www.hotelamsterdam.com;52.171902;4.28061;5367;4
 ;Hotel Atsterdem
 ;Damstraat 20
 1692;Hotel Berlin;Strasse 4;123456;Berlin;4567890;www.hotelberlin.com;43.218571;6.862009;5368;3
 2300;Hotel Barcelona;Avenue 3;AAA 123;Barcelona;3566677;;54.171902;6.102174;5371;4
 ;Hotel Barca
```

Good:

```
1204;Hotel New York;Street 4;AABBCC;New York;12345679;www.hotelnewyork.com;52.3662946;3.876277;5365;3
783;Hotel Amsterdam;Damstraat 10;1234 AB;Amsterdam;234567890;www.hotelamsterdam.com;52.171902;4.28061;5367;4;Hotel Atsterdem;Damstraat 20
1692;Hotel Berlin;Strasse 4;123456;Berlin;4567890;www.hotelberlin.com;43.218571;6.862009;5368;3
2300;Hotel Barcelona;Avenue 3;AAA 123;Barcelona;3566677;;54.171902;6.102174;5371;4;Hotel Barca
```

This is the script I've been using, i know it's probably not the most sophisticated way of getting there but I'm afraid i just can't do much better.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings; 

 if ($#ARGV != 4){
print "4 namen opgeven\n";
exit;
} 

 my $inputfile1=$ARGV[0];
 my $inputfile2=$ARGV[1];
 my $outputfile1=$ARGV[2];
 my $outputfile2=$ARGV[3];
 my $outputfile3=$ARGV[4];

 open(INFILE1,$inputfile1) || die "Not found :$!\n";
 open(INFILE2,$inputfile2) || die "Not found :$!\n";
 open(OUTFILE_1,">$outputfile1") || die "In use :$!\n";
 open(OUTFILE_2,">$outputfile2") || die "In use :$!\n";
 open(OUTFILE_3,">$outputfile3") || die "In use :$!\n";

 my $i = 0;
 my $j = 0;
 my $newline = 0;

 my @infile1=<INFILE1>;
 my @infile2=<INFILE2>;

 foreach ( @infile1 ){
    s/"//g;
    my @elements = split(";",$infile1[$i]);
    chomp(@elements);
    $j = 0;

    foreach ( @infile2 ){
        s/"//g;
        my @loopelements = split(";",$infile2[$j]);
        #chomp(@loopelements);
        $newline = 0;

        if ($elements[10] == $loopelements[10]){

            $newline = 1;

            if ($elements[1] ne $loopelements[1]){
                push(@elements, $loopelements[1]."\n");
                }
            if ($elements[2] ne $loopelements[2]){
                push(@elements, $loopelements[2]."\n");
                }                   
            if ($elements[3] ne $loopelements[3]){
                push(@elements, $loopelements[3]."\n");             
                }                   
            if ($elements[4] ne $loopelements[4]){
                push(@elements, $loopelements[4]."\n"); 
                }                   
            if ($elements[5] ne $loopelements[5]){
                push(@elements, $loopelements[5]."\n");
                }   
            if ($elements[6] ne $loopelements[6]){
                push(@elements, $loopelements[6]."\n");
                }               
            } 

        $j = $j+1;
        }

if ($newline == 0){
    $elements[11] = $elements[11]."\n";
    }       

@elements = join(";",@elements);    
print OUTFILE_1 "@elements";
$i = $i+1;
}

 close(INFILE1);
 close(INFILE2);
 close(OUTFILE_1);
 close(OUTFILE_2);
 close(OUTFILE_3);
```

Comment: What do you think the `."\n"` does?

Comment: seeing as the element gets pushed at the end of the array it ads a newline so the next line is actually at the next line and not after the last added element. That was my idea? Is it incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are doing stuff that would be handled much more easily by a database.  I would consider changing your design.  It would make your life much easier in the long run.

Installing something like MySQL is not too hard.  But you don't even have to do that to use databases with Perl.  There are several completely self-contained solutions that give you a database in Perl.  Look at [`DBD::SQLite`](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/DBD-SQLite-0.31/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm), for example.  All you need to do is install a Perl module, and you have a complete database.

Maybe you are stuck with this format for some reason (such as your boss...).  But even if you have to keep the files in this format, you could *still* work with them as if they were a database.  [`DBD::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/DBD-CSV-0.38/lib/DBD/CSV.pm) does exactly that!